# Oracle SQL query - Get column value from alternate table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to SQL and tried searching for responses in the forum but could not get any.

I have 3 tables from which i need to retrieve data.

```
Table 1:
ID* | Field 1 | Field 2 | 
1   | ABC     | XYZ



Table 2:
ID-FK from table 1 | Company - Vendor | Company - Supplier
1                  | 3                 | 2
```

One of the company value could be null

```
Table 3 (Company table)
Company ID | Company name
1          | Company A
2          | Company B
3          | Company C
```

Required output :

```
ID | Field 1 | Company - Vendor | Company - Supplier
1  | ABC     | Company C        | Company B
```

inner join mentioned in some posts did not work for me (Or i did not know how to work it)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the query you tried and look up left join.

Comment: Do you use `mysql` or `oracle`? Please edit your question, remove wrong tag .

Comment: Your problem is a very basic question. `INNER JOIN` should work fine for yours. Please read [inner_join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) and try again. One it work, you will find that it is very easy to use.

Comment: 'One of the company value could be null' it would be better if you if your sample data illustrated your problem. As it is it's not clear if you mean the company value in table 2 or table 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  t1.ID,
    t1."Field 1",
    (select x."Company Name" from "Table 3" where "Company ID" = t2."Company - Vendor") as "Company - Vendor",
    (select x."Company Name" from "Table 3" where "Company ID" = t2."Company - Supplier") as "Company - Supplier"
from "Table 1" t1
   join "Table 2" t2 on t1.id = t2."ID-FK"
```

Comment: It works if you are using Oracle, not sure about MySQL. I submitted this answer as you attached the question with Oracle too.

Comment: This works. We are using java to generate the SQL. The modular nature of the query also helps us to easily form the sql statement.

Comment: I am not able to upvote because it says  i have less than 15 reputations. Sorry for not able to upvote.

Comment: No problem, its an restriction by the site.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need 2 left joins to get company and vendor so given

```
drop table if exists table1,table2,table3;

create table table1(ID int, Field1 varchar(3), Field2 varchar(3)); 
insert into table1 values
(1   , 'ABC'     , 'XYZ');

create table Table2(IDFK int,  CompanyVendor int, CompanySupplier int);
insert into table2 values
(1                  , 3                 , 2),
(1                  , 3                 , null),
(1                  , null                , 2),
(1                  , 4                 , 5),
(1                  , 1                 , 2)
;

create table Table3 (CompanyID int, name varchar(20));
insert into table3 values
(1          , 'Company A'),
(2          , 'Company B'),
(3          , 'Company C');
```

This query

```
select t1.*,t2.companyvendor,t3.name Vendorname,
         t2.companysupplier,t4.name Suppliername
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t2.idfk = t1.id
left join table3 t3 on t3.CompanyID = t2.companyvendor
left join table3 t4 on t4.CompanyID = t2.companysupplier
;
```

Yields this result

```
+------+--------+--------+---------------+------------+-----------------+--------------+
| ID   | Field1 | Field2 | companyvendor | Vendorname | companysupplier | Suppliername |
+------+--------+--------+---------------+------------+-----------------+--------------+
|    1 | ABC    | XYZ    |             1 | Company A  |               2 | Company B    |
|    1 | ABC    | XYZ    |             3 | Company C  |               2 | Company B    |
|    1 | ABC    | XYZ    |          NULL | NULL       |               2 | Company B    |
|    1 | ABC    | XYZ    |             3 | Company C  |            NULL | NULL         |
|    1 | ABC    | XYZ    |             4 | NULL       |               5 | NULL         |
+------+--------+--------+---------------+------------+-----------------+--------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

BTW never use hyphen (-) as an entity name and don't use whitespace.